# How to extract from a set of lists those that contain a specified element?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the list below. Suppose I want all those lists that contain element A416. I should get `{A1,A2,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A2,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A3,A416,A415,A411,G1}` and `{A416,A415,A411,G1}`.

```
lst={{A1,A2,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A2,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A3,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A4,A416,A415,A411,G1},{A1001,A68,A205,G1},{A403,A68,A205,G1},{A68,A205,G1},{A11,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A12,A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A13,A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A14,A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A142,G1},{G1},{A15,A14,A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A150,G1},{A158,G1},{A161,A165,A142,G1},{A165,A142,G1},{A162,A165,A142,G1},{A18,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A19,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A29,A28,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A38,A37,A70,A503,G1},{A416,A415,A411,G1},{A46,A45,A49,A150,G1},{A54,A53,A57,A158,G1},{A9,A8,A11,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A20,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A202,A205,G1},{A205,G1},{A203,A202,A205,G1},{A204,A205,G1},{A206,A205,G1},{A207,A206,A205,G1},{A208,A204,A205,G1},{A23,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A24,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A25,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A26,A27,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A27,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A28,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A301,G1},{A302,A202,A205,G1},{A303,A301,G1},{A304,A302,A202,A205,G1},{A305,A303,A301,G1},{A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A32,A409,A57,A158,G1},{A409,A57,A158,G1},{A33,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A40,A41,A142,G1},{A48,A49,A150,G1},{A56,A57,A158,G1},{A35,A36,A70,A503,G1},{A36,A70,A503,G1},{A41,A142,G1},{A70,A503,G1},{A91,A601,G1},{A37,A70,A503,G1},{A401,A403,A68,A205,G1},{A402,A403,A68,A205,G1},{A405,A406,A501,A5200,G1},{A406,A501,A5200,G1},{A501,A5200,G1},{A407,A408,G1},{A408,G1},{A57,A158,G1},{A410,A409,A57,A158,G1},{A411,G1},{A412,A411,G1},{A413,A414,A411,G1},{A414,A411,G1},{A415,A411,G1},{A417,A408,G1},{A43,A44,A49,A150,G1},{A44,A49,A150,G1},{A49,A150,G1},{A69,A302,A202,A205,G1},{A45,A49,A150,G1},{A504,G1},{A5200,G1},{A5210,G1},{A522,G1},{A5230,G1},{A502,G1},{A503,G1},{A505,G1},{A506,A504,G1},{A507,A503,G1},{A508,A507,A503,G1},{A509,A507,A503,G1},{A51,A52,A57,A158,G1},{A52,A57,A158,G1},{A510,A509,A507,A503,G1},{A511,A509,A507,A503,G1},{A512,A507,A503,G1},{A5201,A501,A5200,G1},{A5211,A501,A5200,G1},{A5231,A501,A5200,G1},{A524,A501,A5200,G1},{A525,A501,A5200,G1},{A526,A501,A5200,G1},{A527,A501,A5200,G1},{A53,A57,A158,G1},{A59,A162,A165,A142,G1},{A60,A63,A165,A142,G1},{A6,A7,A11,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A7,A11,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A63,A165,A142,G1},{A601,G1},{A602,A604,A601,G1},{A603,A601,G1},{A604,A601,G1},{A605,A608,G1},{A608,G1},{A606,A608,G1},{A607,A605,A608,G1},{A609,A608,G1},{A610,A609,A608,G1},{A611,A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A612,A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A614,A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A615,A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A616,A613,A610,A609,A608,G1},{A64,A165,A142,G1},{A66,A13,A17,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A67,A68,A205,G1},{A8,A11,A31,A34,A48,A49,A150,G1},{A88888,A501,A5200,G1},{A90,A41,A142,G1},{A99999,A501,A5200,G1},{A502,G1}}
```

Comment: `Cases[lst,{___,A416,___}]` That is three _ before and after A416 so that it matches zero or more other things before and after.

Comment: wonderful ... many thanks, Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or...

```
Select[lst, MemberQ[#, A416] &]
```

Comment: thank you, David!